# SQL data type time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, insert, sqldatatypes

Is it possible to create a data type in SQL similar to time that only displays the hour and minutes instead of the hour, minutes and seconds.

For example, If I inserted values into a table with the data type time I would get hh:mm:ss. How could I insert a value that only displays hh:mm?

Comment: Better to store the data as TIME and truncate in the presentation/display layer (or use int to store minutes if the value can exceed 24 hours)

Comment: Store it was TIME, you'll be grateful when client requirements change in 6 months time and they need seconds too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIME`. More generally, the format in which you want something displayed should not affect your decision of the format in which it should be stored.